# How to run the rule analysis to my project. Sonarqube 6.5, MSBuild 3.0.2?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

-I have the MSBuild in the path: `D:\sonarqube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe`
The project I want to analyze in the path:

```
D:\SYACSoftware\DG
TOKEN-->SyacToken2017:b7af44b5a98ce10e53d916b71f22a668ff93ece4
KEY:SYAC-DG
```

-When I execute the commands, I can't execute the analysis with the following message:

> The file name, the directory name or the syntax of the volume label are not correct.

This appears in the **sonar.login** tag and in the **Sonar.host**
-I am using the following commands in the CMD, but I do not get results:

[image: Error in Commands]

Comment: Why using spaces in the path before MSBuild.exe?

Comment: You cannot use '\' as a way to split the command onto multiple lines with cmd. Please try to put all the arguments on the same line (i.e. without the\)

Comment: -First part works, but I still can not finish the analysis, when I execute the following:
        `Msbuild.exe / t: Rebuild`
                                           
-Displays the message:
    "MsBuild.exe" is not recognized as an internal command or External, program, or executable batch file.
[link](http://prntscr.com/g8tvuq)

Comment: The MSBuild location is not added to your PATH environment by default so you have to use the full path to the exe.

Comment: -Finally an analysis was executed, but it is never updated on the SONARQUBE server. It is showing many times the same message: "error CS0246: The name of the type or the 'PersistentAttribute' namespace was not found (is it missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

See: <http://prntscr.com/g8xiqc>

Comment: I finally finished the statement when I removed the old sonar-project.properties file, but I would like to know why that error occurs: 'error CS0246: The name of the type or the 'XXXXXX' namespace was not found Directive or an assembly reference?) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Analysis worked as follows: adding the location of the MSBuild to the environment path, the commands were successfully executed:

`D: \ sonarqube \ bin \ SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin / k: "SYAC-DG" /n:"DG.Net-WPF "/v:"2017.08.11-1.0" / d: "sonar. Host.url = http: // localhost: 9000 "/d:"sonar.login=b7af44b5a98ce10e53d916b71f22a668ff93ece4"`

`MSBuild.exe / t: Rebuild`

`D: \ SYACSoftware \ DG> SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:"sonar.login=b7af44b5a98ce10e53d916b71f22a668ff93ece4 "`